# MySQL Order By different field if condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with events, some of them are concerts, which have the timestamp column filled. Some are quizes, and since they are recurring events, they dont have timestamp set, but two other columns i call day and time.

I need a select to order this table after `TIME(timestamp) asc`, except when the column `event_type = 'quiz'`, then it should order by the column `time` instead.

Only the "hour:minute" part needs to be taken into account, not the day.

How can I go about doing this? See example table below:

```
title      event_type timestamp           day       time
concert_1  music      2015-02-09 18:00:00
quiz_1     quiz       0000-00-00 00:00:00 Monday    16:30
concert_2  music      2015-02-10 19:00:00
quiz_2     quiz       0000-00-00 00:00:00 Tuesday   14:00
```

Result should be:

```
title      event_type timestamp           day       time
quiz_2     quiz       0000-00-00 00:00:00 Tuesday   14:00
quiz_1     quiz       0000-00-00 00:00:00 Monday    16:30
concert_1  music      2015-02-09 18:00:00
concert_2  music      2015-02-10 19:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional expression to return one or the other.

For example:

```
 ORDER BY IF(t.event_type='quiz',t.time,TIME(t.timestamp))
```

The MySQL `IF()` function evaluates the first argument as a boolean; if the result is TRUE, it returns the second argument, otherwise, it returns the third argument.

ANSI compliant equivalent would be

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.event_type = 'quiz' THEN t.time ELSE TIME(t.timestamp) END
```

---

This assumes that the `time` column is declared as  a `TIME` datatype, and the `timestamp` column is declared as `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype. If this isn't the case, then we'd want to return expressions that return the same datatype, in a canonical format, so they can be sorted correctly.